# How to execute a file residing in memory with BoxedAPP

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, stream, virtualization, virtual-file

I've purchased a license of BoxedAPP and when I wrote for help to the support mail I got any answer.

I've downloaded the SDK examples but all the important examples are in C# (and even if I use a translator I can't understand it), and the vb.net examples are for store files not executing they.

My question is simple, How I can use BoxedAPP to store a file in memory (Virtualize a file) and then execute it from memory?

For example I want to virtualize a Video file named "test.avi" as "my.resources.test" and then execute it with "process.start", this is what I've tryed to virtualize my recurse but don't run:

```
    BoxedAppSDK.NativeMethods.BoxedAppSDK_CreateVirtualFile(My.Resources.test, _
                                                            BoxedAppSDK.NativeMethods.EFileAccess.GenericAll, _
                                                            BoxedAppSDK.NativeMethods.EFileShare.None, IntPtr.Zero, _
                                                            BoxedAppSDK.NativeMethods.ECreationDisposition.New, _
                                                            BoxedAppSDK.NativeMethods.EFileAttributes.Normal, _
                                                            IntPtr.Zero)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument should be a string, check the function declaration:

```
    <DllImport("bxsdk32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Public Shared Function BoxedAppSDK_CreateVirtualFile( _
    ByVal lpFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As EFileAccess, _
    ByVal dwShareMode As EFileShare, _
    ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As IntPtr, _
    ByVal dwCreationDisposition As ECreationDisposition, _
    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As EFileAttributes, _
    ByVal hTemplateFile As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function
```

Also what does BoxedAppSDK_CreateVirtualFile return?